# Samsung's device care app and running services option in developers settings show two different values for the amount of RAM free on my device

Tags: ram, developer-options

As shown by Samsung:- https://m.imgur.com/gallery/yoiOnlS

As shown by developer options by Android:- https://m.imgur.com/gallery/OzNwRMO

Why is it happening? Why is Samsung lying?

Comment: Both of your images are removed. Please re-add here in the post. Also, what `free -h` and `dumpsys meminfo | grep -A10 'Total RAM'` show?

Comment: https://imgur.com/Gus2qzG - Device care @IrfanLatif

Comment: https://imgur.com/y8N7Z6G - Developer options @IrfanLatif

Comment: What about the remaining part of my query?

Comment: @IrfanLatif dang sorry I forgot to mention the results. The first one shows that 2.6/2.6 gb of RAM is being used and the second one says "grep" is not recognized as an internal or external command.